# Passing method to a function in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass a method, specifically a method of the string class, to a function which will run it.  My code looks something like:

```
def foo (list):
    for in_str in list[0]:
        print(in_str.list[1]())

# format of list
list = [
    [["Hello world!", "helloworld"], str.isalpha]
]
```

The desired operation of the function would be to invoke the isalpha method on the string in_str then print the result.  This doesn't work because in_str obviously doesn't have the attribute list, but I want to know how to make list[1] reference the method.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def foo (l):
    for in_str in l[0]:
        print(l[1](in_str))

# format of list
l = [["Hello world!", "helloworld"], str.isalpha]
print(foo(l))
```

You need to pass a string to `str.isalpha`, also you have an extra pair of brackets in the list.

```
In [2]: foo(l)
False
True
```

If you just want to pass a function then pass it as a parameter and just pass a list of strings:

```
def foo(l, func):
    for in_str in l[0]:
       print(func(in_str))


l = ["Hello world!", "helloworld"]

print(foo(l,str.isalpha))
```

A nicer way may be to use `map` to map the func to each string:

```
def foo(l,func):
    return  map(func,l) # list(map(...) python 3

print(foo(l,str.isalpha))
```

Comment: Yep! That's the perfect answer. **But**, you say *also you have an extra pair of brackets in the list*, What if the OP calls the function as `print(foo(l[0]))`

Comment: @BhargavRao, iI think it was a typo by the OP, as using `l[0]`, `in_str` `would be a list. If not we can do a little change

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm wording this properly, but what I desire the function to do is invoke in_str.isalpha() by passing it as a parameter.  My actual program is much larger and has many different methods to pass, but need to be loaded by a list.

Comment: @SuperUser320, you can simply pass it as a parameter

Comment: Hmm.  I think I have larger issues.  When I run that in the python shell it works, yet in my program it returns [] instead of "True" or "False"

Comment: What does you actual input look like?

Comment: Oy, that was a big typo.  I was using a format and typed [], instead of {}.  It was working the whole time -_-.  Well, at least I've learned a lot about what's actually going on behind the scenes!

Answer (score 1):

Either you call the function `isalpha` with a string as an argument:

```
str.isalpha('Hello World!")
```

or as an object oriented approach:

```
'Hello World'.isalpha()
```

In your case we also need to correct some indices. I also changed the variable name `list` because it shadows the [built-in list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) function.

```
def foo(anestedlist):
    for a_str in anestedlist[0][0]:
        print(anestedlist[0][1](a_str))

# format of list
anestedlist = [[["Hello world!", "helloworld"], str.isalpha]]
```

and

```
foo(anestedlist)
```

prints

```
False
True
```

The important part here is

```
print(anestedlist[0][1](a_str))
```

which translates to `str.isalpha(a_str)`, i.e. passing a string as an argument.